Black Activities Overview After Wake Up
I have switched to Ubuntu 24.04.01 a week ago and it's a fresh install. The problem is when I suspend and wake up my computer, the activities overview doesn't work and it's just black screen. The alt-tab screen is also black. I have two gnome extensions, dash to dock and soft brightness plus. Please see the images below.



